# Represent xml as a family tree

Tags: xml, treeview, xml-parsing, expression-trees

How do i convert an XML to a graph readable format? I tried GraphViz, but I get syntax error.

Sample input XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
    <EFG>
        <Events>
            <Event>
                <EventId>e2755731202</EventId>
                <Type>SYSTEM INTERACTION</Type>
                <Listeners>Project$W1Listener</Listeners>
            </Event>
            ...
       </Events>
       <EventGraph>
        <Row>
            <E>1</E>
            <E>1</E>
            <E>0</E>
            <E>0</E>
            <E>0</E>
        </Row>
        ...
   </EventGraph>
</EFG>

Error: <gvedit>:1: syntax error near line 1
context: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" >>>  ?> <<<
```

Any suggestion what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I googled this. It looks like, if you want to use GraphViz, that you'll need to transform your XML to a format compliant with the GXL XSD schema:

[GXL Schema](http://www.gupro.de/GXL/xmlschema/xmlschema.html)

Either generate your XML in the appropriate format or else use an XSL tor transform it.

Comment: Rather than GXL, I use DotML, which is an XML-encoded version of the GraphViz dot language. But certainly, to get this data into GraphViz the first step is to transform it into something that GraphViz understands, typically using XSLT.

Comment: @MichaelKay +1 fair point. GraphViz won't know how to handle the XML that Matt has above., he's gotta transform it.

Comment: [Using GXL doesn't really appear to work.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738054/gxl-for-graphviz-syntax-alternatives)  What I do is write an XSLT or Perl script to generate CSV format (one node name per line, one pair of node names per line for edges) and convert that to Graphviz format with one of my own scripts, e.g. [csv2dot](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/csv2dot).